# start a phone call using the built in phone dialer

Tags: android, phone-call

I would like to make a phone call from an application.
Is it possible to restrict the options only to call from the built-in phone application, not to show Viber, Skype or Whatsapp as options?

Here is my code:

```
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ adapter.getItem(position).getContent()));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.call_number)));
```

I would like to look like this:

[image]

and not like this (if I have installed Viber and Skype):

[image]

I try with this code:

```
public static Intent callfromDefaultDialer(Context ctxt, String no) {

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + no));
    PackageManager pm = ctxt.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo info : list) {
        String pkgnam = info.activityInfo.packageName;
        if (pkgnam.toLowerCase().equals("com.android.phone")) {
            i.setClassName(pkgnam, info.activityInfo.name);
            return i;
        }
    }

    return i;
}
```

and this opens Skype as a choice also I don't know why?

Comment: Please allow the *user* to choose how the *user* wants to place the call. It is the *user's* device, not yours.

Comment: I think you have to manually specify the package name of the phone app in the Intent

Comment: Please look at the edit of my question

Comment: That's because Skype is a valid choice.

Comment: Did you see my answer? Did you try? With only this two line of code in all my phones Skype or Whatsapp are not an option. Always the default dialer is triggered. Don't create a chooser, just go straight ahead with the default dialer intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ACTION_CALL Intent flag

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
 startActivity(intent);
```

But that is no more the right choice.

You need to ask for direct phone access permission in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

If you use only this two line of code you will have the dialer and not Skype.

Don't create a chooser, just go straight ahead with the default dialer intent.

Check also at the default phone dialer application in your phone, is this Skype?

Moreover you shold also check if the GSM Networks is available.